# Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I have read few solutions on here about the same but still cant seem to get passed this error. Im using axios as my http client and the app is a nextjs app

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Home() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const credentials ={username: username, password: password}

    const user = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', credentials);
    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        
        <label htmlFor='username'>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onChange={e=> setUsername(e.target)} />

        <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" onChange={e=> setPassword(e.target)} />

        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to input value from the event. not the entire target

```
setUsername(e.target.value) 
setPassword(e.target.value)
```

also, add `value` to inputs

```
<input value={username}  ...
```